# Как реализовать расчет расстояния по яндекс картам после ввода адреса?

Tags: javascript, яндекс-карта-api

Получается сейчас не могу добиться следующего, чтоб при вводе и выборе адреса в input который создал, происходил расчет доставки от пункта А в пункт Б и стоимость выводилась в
`id="cost"` а км в `id="km"`.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Также хотел убрать данный блок, чтоб была карта и точка начальная. Но если панель не инициализирую то и вовсе расчета не происходит.

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
  // Стоимость за километр.
  var DELIVERY_TARIFF = 100,
    // Минимальная стоимость.
    MINIMUM_COST = 200,
    suggestView = new ymaps.SuggestView('suggest', {
        provider: {
          suggest: (function(request, options) {
            return ymaps.suggest("Алматы, " + request);

          })
        }
      }

    ),
    myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
      center: [76.912945, 43.196503],
      zoom: 9,
      controls: []
    }),
    // Создадим панель маршрутизации.
    routePanelControl = new ymaps.control.RoutePanel({
      /*options: {
                        // Добавим заголовок панели.
                        showHeader: true,
                        title: 'Расчёт доставки'
                    }*/
    }),
    zoomControl = new ymaps.control.ZoomControl({
      options: {
        size: 'small',
        float: 'none',
        position: {
          bottom: 145,
          right: 10
        }
      }
    });
  // Пользователь сможет построить только автомобильный маршрут.
  routePanelControl.routePanel.options.set({
    types: {
      auto: true
    }
  });

  // Если вы хотите задать неизменяемую точку "откуда", раскомментируйте код ниже.
  routePanelControl.routePanel.state.set({
    fromEnabled: false,
    from: 'Алматы, Розыбакиева, 247а'
    // to: 'Алматы, улица Папанина, 52А'
  });

  myMap.controls.add(routePanelControl).add(zoomControl);

  // Получим ссылку на маршрут.
  routePanelControl.routePanel.getRouteAsync().then(function(route) {

    // Повесим обработчик на событие построения маршрута.
    route.model.events.add('requestsuccess', function() {

      var activeRoute = route.getActiveRoute();
      if (activeRoute) {
        // Получим протяженность маршрута.
        var length = route.getActiveRoute().properties.get("distance"),
          // Вычислим стоимость доставки.
          price = calculate(Math.round(length.value / 1000)),
          // Создадим макет содержимого балуна маршрута.
          balloonContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
            '<span>Расстояние: ' + length.text + '.</span><br/>' +
            '<span style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic">Стоимость доставки: ' +
            price + ' ТГ.</span>');
        // Зададим этот макет для содержимого балуна.
        route.options.set('routeBalloonContentLayout', balloonContentLayout);
      }
    });

  });
  // Функция, вычисляющая стоимость доставки.
  function calculate(routeLength) {
    return Math.max(routeLength * DELIVERY_TARIFF, MINIMUM_COST);
  }
}
```

```css
.input {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?apikey=b9cb3120-b3f9-42d1-9514-9bbc06532690&amp;lang=ru_RU"></script>
<input name="address" type="text" id="suggest" value="" class="input">
<div id="cost"> </div>
<div id="km"> </div>
<div id="map" style="height: 300px;margin-bottom:30px;"> </div>
```